# Prioritizing class specializations

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say we have a dual parametrized template like

```
template<class A, class B>
class Class { .... };
```

and that there are specializations for a particular `A` and a particular `B`

```
template<class B> class Class<A1,B> { .... };
template<class A> class Class<A,B1> { .... };
```

Now, when I have to instantiate `Class<A1,B1>` the compiler complains for ambiguity since it find `<A,B1>` and `<A1,B>` equally usable.

The problem can of course be eliminated by adding an `<A1,B1>` specialization, but -in my context- it will be identical `<A1,B>`.

Is there a way to eliminate the ambiguity without repeating the entire `<A1,B>` full code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility is to simply forbid the second specialization to be selected:

```
template<class A, class B, class=void>
class Class {};

template<class B>
class Class<A1,B> {};

template<class A>
class Class<A, B1, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<A,A1>::value>::type> {};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a405018ca6428c80).

Answer (score 6):

I'd add a third default parameter to the base template and allow each specialization to be picked up through SFINAE:

```
template<class A, class B, 
         class extra = void /* Enable/disable specialization through SFINAE */>
class Class { public: void hello() {std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;} };

template<class B> class Class<A1, B> { 
 public: 
 void hello() {std::cout << "First" << std::endl;} 
};
template<class A> class Class<A, B1, 
                   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<A, A1>::value>::type> {
  public: 
  void hello() {std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;} 
};

int main()
{     
  Class<A1,B1> obj;// The first one is picked up
  obj.hello();
  Class<A,B1> obj2; // The second one is picked up
  obj2.hello();
  Class<A,B> obj3; // Base
  obj3.hello();
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/DKibc2)</kbd>

or even simpler (depending if it's acceptable in your use cases):

```
template<class A, class B, bool AisA1 = std::is_same<A,A1>::value>
class Class { public: void hello() {std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;} };

template<class B> class Class<A1, B, true /* Pick this when A == A1 */> { 
 public: void hello() {std::cout << "First" << std::endl;} 
};
template<class A> class Class<A, B1, false> { 
 public: void hello() {std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;} 
};
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/OT737S)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I haven't tested it, and I'm by no means a template expert.

My idea: give that duplicated specialization a name, so you can refer to it:

```
template<class B> classA1 { ... }; // code goes here.

template<class B> class Class<A1,B> : public classA1<B> {};
template<> Class<A1,B1> : public classA1<B1> {};
```